# How to get UGC posts of an organization based on media category in Linkedin v2 API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Is there any parameter used to filter or retrieve UGC post based on media category(Images,videos)

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&sortBy=CREATED&authors=List(organization urn)
```